# URL parameters by Hyperlink column datagrid in aspx

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, hyperlink

I have class `ITEM` containing public property of `ID` and `Namee`.  I am trying the hyperlink url parameters option with data grid.

Following is the code of the page.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ExamList.aspx.vb" Inherits="Tiko.ExamList" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataTextField="Namee" 
                HeaderText="Namee" NavigateUrl="~/Loggedin/Admin/MakeExam.aspx?exid={0}"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Loggedin/Admin/MakeExam.aspx?exid={0}"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the code for filling the data.

```
Public Class ExamList
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'GridView1.DataSource = DataModule.Exams_listall((CType(Session("Login"), TikoClasses.Login)).Inst_ID)
        GridView1.DataSource = DataModule.Exams_listall(0)
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

End Class
```

The data is a list of `ITEMS` class as metioned earlier.  When I run the page, I see only `~/Loggedin/Admin/MakeExam.aspx?exid={0}` as link for all rows in that column.  Could you please tell me what wrong have I done here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked. The issue was data ID contains date format, as a result ":" and " " were added, hence no url was being framed

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `NavigateURL` as I think it is overriding your `DataNavigateURLFormatString`

Comment: Doing that is removing the hyperlink totally.

Comment: Odd. According to MSDN it is correct and I have even done an example and copied your markup directly and it still works. I take it the ID and Namee fields are OK elswhere?

Comment: It worked with a dataset, it doesn't matter where the values are coming from. Have you checked the datasource via a breakpoint to make sure the ID is there? There isn't anything wrong with the code the problem lies elsewhere i'm sure.

Comment: I have checked them, the data is being populated into the table, however, only the hyperlink is not changing.

Comment: Finally worked.  The issue was data ID contains date format, as a result ":" and " " were added, hence no url  was being framed.  Thank you for the support @PunkyGuy